# Converting a base64-encoded jpeg to a png in React in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, png, image-conversion

I have a base64-encoded jpeg string that I'm holding in state in React. I've been trying to work out how to convert it to a png format base64 string browser-side.

I briefly looked at [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp), but I found that requires a server side node.js environment. I don't really want to have to write my own conversion script. Further searching on npm hasn't yielded anything for me.

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

Comment: My initial thought would be to draw the JPEG to a canvas with `drawImage()`, then call `toDataURL()` on that canvas. PNG is the default format when using toDataURL, so you shouldn't even need an argument to it.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk That's interesting, I'll research that. Thanks. Please feel free to make an answer if you think that will solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but you should be able to set the base64 JPEG as the source of an image, then draw that image to a canvas using `context.drawImage`; once it's on a canvas, you can use `canvas.toDataURL()` to get a base64 PNG of it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested and this works perfectly. Good solution!